# R: time series monthly max adjusted by group

Tags: r, time-series, max

I have a df like that (head):

```
        date  Value
1: 2016-12-31 169361280
2: 2017-01-01 169383153
3: 2017-01-02 169494585
4: 2017-01-03 167106852
5: 2017-01-04 166750164
6: 2017-01-05 164086438
```

I would like to calculate a ratio, for that reason I need the max of every period. The max it´s normally the last day of the month but sometime It could be some days after and before (28,29,30,31,01,02).

In order to calculate it properly I would like to assign to my reference date (the last day of the month) the max value of this group of days to be sure that the ratio reflects what it supossed to.

This could be a reproducible example:

```
Start<-as.Date("2016-12-31")
End<-Sys.Date()
window<-data.table(seq(Start,End,by='1 day'))
dt<-cbind(window,rep(rnorm(nrow(window))))
colnames(dt)<-c("date","value")

# Create a Dateseq

DateSeq <- function(st, en, freq) {
st <- as.Date(as.yearmon(st)) 
en <- as.Date(as.yearmon(en)) 
as.Date(as.yearmon(seq(st, en, by = paste(as.character(12/freq), 
"months"))), frac = 1)
}

# df to be fulfilled with the group max.

Value.Max.Month<-data.frame(DateSeq(Start,End,12))

colnames(Value.Max.Month)<-c("date")

         date
1  2016-12-31
2  2017-01-31
3  2017-02-28
4  2017-03-31
5  2017-04-30
6  2017-05-31
7  2017-06-30
8  2017-07-31
9  2017-08-31
10 2017-09-30
11 2017-10-31
12 2017-11-30
13 2017-12-31
14 2018-01-31
15 2018-02-28
16 2018-03-31
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data.table`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
Start  <- as.Date("2016-12-31")
End    <- Sys.Date()
window <- data.table(seq(Start,End,by='1 day'))
dt     <- cbind(window,rep(rnorm(nrow(window))))

colnames(dt) <- c("date","value")
dt <- data.table(dt)

dt[,period := as.Date(as.yearmon(date)) %m+% months(1) - 1,][, maximum:=max(value), by=period][, unique(maximum), by=period]
```

In the first expression we create a new column called `period`. Then we group by this new column and look for the maximum in `value`. In the last expression we just output these unique rows.

Notice that to get the last day of each period we add one month using `lubridate` and then substract 1 day.
The output is:

```
       period         V1
 1: 2016-12-31 -0.7832116
 2: 2017-01-31  2.1988660
 3: 2017-02-28  1.6644812
 4: 2017-03-31  1.2464980
 5: 2017-04-30  2.8268820
 6: 2017-05-31  1.7963104
 7: 2017-06-30  1.3612476
 8: 2017-07-31  1.7325457
 9: 2017-08-31  2.7503439
10: 2017-09-30  2.4369036
11: 2017-10-31  2.4544802
12: 2017-11-30  3.1477730
13: 2017-12-31  2.8461506
14: 2018-01-31  1.8862944
15: 2018-02-28  1.8946470
16: 2018-03-31  0.7864341
```